# Highcharts Gantt - how to force data labels to always be above milestones?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highcharts-gantt

I'm building a milestone comparison chart using Highcharts Gantt.

Each of my milestones has a short acronym for the milestone "type", which I want to show as data labels, and I want them to always be *above* the milestone marker.

I managed to get them outside the markers by setting

```
dataLabels: {
    inside: false
}
```

on the series, but Highcharts is only putting the labels above the markers on the first row of data, on subsequent rows it's putting the labels below:

[image: screen shot of label placement]

I tired playing around with the `verticalAlignment` setting, but that doesn't seem to do what I want it to do.

How can I force Highcharts to always position the data labels above the milestone markers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position data labels above the markers by using `y` property:

```
  series: [{
      ...,
      milestone: true,
      dataLabels: {
        ...,
        y: -10
      }
    }, ...]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yv641op0/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/series.gantt.dataLabels.y

Comment: Ugh, one of those ones that was staring me right in the face... :)